# Host a website on the raspberry pi to display local sensor data

Tags: python, web-server

I have been enlisted by the local engineering club (as a programmer myself) to help with their hydroponics project. Basically they are needing help accessing the Pi remotely and this is as much as i know as of now. I promised to do some research and am in need of some help.

What would be the best way to deploy a server on the raspberry pi in 2018 assuming I am most familiar with python and flask when it comes to the Pi?

Comment: There's nothing specific in this about the Pi, so it's really off-topic here.  Google terms like Apache and LAMP.

Comment: Presumably, being familiar with Flask means you are already familiar with how to run a web server, so what's your problem?

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/README.md Apache setup is simpler, but NGINX is better suited to the resources on the Pi See https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/python-web-server-with-flask

Comment: @Jaromanda X i am familiar with how to run a flask webserver. However, I am not sure why people recommend things like nginx and apache. I understand it may be faster and/or more secure but I dont want to use them without understanding what they are for and whether or not they are the right tool for the job.

Comment: Furthermore when I do use nginx i am having trouble configuring it to do an mjpeg stream. Its all a little over my head. I'm used to simple copy/paste raspberry pi tutorials lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi is powerful enough to host any web application targeted for limited number of users. Typical use case could be an IoT application designed for Smart Home or Building.
Though you can have a full stack application (Web + App + DB) on raspberry Pi with SQLite or MySQL DB; here we are going to keep it simple with Web and App tiers.

To execute Python Code with respect to the HTTP Request we need uWSGI Server between our Web Server and Python Web Application. In this example we are going to use “uwsgi” which is one of the most popular uWSGI Servers.

In following diagram you can see the information flow and placement of different components on Raspberry Pi –
.[image]
Following steps will guide you through the installation and configuration of required packages to deploy a basic flask application –
**1. Update and Upgrade Raspberry Pi packages:**

Update Raspberry Pi packages –

`sudo apt-get update`

Upgrade Raspberry Pi Packages –

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

**2. Install NGINX:**

Install NGINX on Raspberry Pi with apt-get –

`sudo apt-get install nginx`

Start NGINX Service –

`sudo service nginx start`

To check the NGINX installation you can type Raspberry Pi’s ip address in your browser and you should see default NGINX page with “Welcome to nginx on Debian!” message.
**3. Install Flask:**

`sudo pip install flask`

**4. Install uWSGI:**

Install build-essentials and python-dev on Raspberry Pi –

`sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev`

Install uWSGI using pip –

`sudo pip install uwsgi`

**5. Create a simple Python Flask App:**

Create a folder in “/home/pi” directory –

`mkdir /home/pi/sampleApp`

Change owner of this directory –

`sudo chown www-data /home/pi/sampleApp`

Create a new file named as “sample_app.py” in “/home/pi/sampleApp” directory –

`sudo vi /home/pi/sampleApp/sample_app.py`

Add following code to “sample_app.py” file –

```
from flask import Flask
first_app = Flask(__name__)

@first_app.route("/")
def first_function():
   return "<html><body><h1 style='color:red'>I am hosted on Raspberry Pi !!!</h1></body></html>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  first_app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**6. Test Flask App with Python and uWSGI:**

Execute `sample_app.py` file with following command. If you don’t see any error type Raspberry Pi’s IP Address with port 5000 in your browser (http://x.x.x.x:5000/) and you should see “I am hosted on Raspberry Pi !!!” in red color.

`python /home/pi/sampleApp/sample_app.py`

After testing Flask app with Python, you may want to test it with uWSGI –

`cd /home/pi/sampleApp/`

`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w sample_app:first_app`

Now you can test your app using port 8000 with Raspberry Pi’s IP Address (http://x.x.x.x:8000/)
**7. create uWSGI Initialisation File:**

create a new file named as `uwsgi_config.ini` in `/home/pi/sampleApp` directory –
`sudo vi /home/pi/sampleApp/uwsgi_config.ini`

Add following code to `uwsgi_config.ini` file –

```
[uwsgi]

chdir = /home/pi/sampleApp
module = sample_app:first_app

master = true
processes = 1
threads = 2

uid = www-data 
gid = www-data
socket = /tmp/sample_app.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

**8. Test uWSGI Initialisation File:**
Execute following command –
`uwsgi --ini /home/pi/sampleApp/uwsgi_config.ini`
Open another session to Raspberry Pi and check if you have `sample_app.sock` file in `/tmp` directory –

`ls /tmp/ |grep sample_app.sock`

If you see `sample_app.sock` file in command output your configuration is correct.
**9. Configure uWSGI to Auto-Start after Reboot:**

Edit `/etc/rc.local` file using following command –

`sudo vi /etc/rc.local`
Add following command in this file before the line `exit 0` –

`/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/pi/sampleApp/uwsgi_config.ini --uid www-data --gid www-data --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi.log`
**10. Configure NGINX to Redirect Web Traffic to uWSGI (Reverse Proxy):**
Remove “default” file from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` –
`sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`
Create a new file named as `sample_app_proxy` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` –
`sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/sample_app_proxy`
Add following configuration in `sample_app_proxy` file –

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name localhost;

 location / { try_files $uri @app; }
 location @app {
 include uwsgi_params;
 uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/sample_app.sock;
 }
}
```

Link `/etc/nginx/sites-available/sample_app_proxy` file to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory –
`sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/sample_app_proxy /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Restart NGINX Service –
`sudo service nginx restart`

With this your Raspberry Pi is ready with a sample Python Flask Web Application. You can type Raspberry Pi’s IP Address in your web browser to access the HTML Page.

Comment: And how do you display local sensor data? That is the headline.

Comment: You can get the sensor from gpio library using database. Many libraries are there

Comment: I would extend your answer with a description how to do it.

Comment: Sure. Please go ahead :)

Comment: I dont understand the significance of using uwsgi and nginx aside from adding security somehow. Could someone please explain? @ShubhenduYadav

Comment: @Daveyman123, both `nginx` and `uwsgi` are production ready (giving speed and security advantages). `uwsgi` replaces the dev server which you likely use whilst building the app, and `nginx` acts as a reverse proxy which external traffic will hit first.  The dev server is in-efficient and can't handle multiple connections well, so you wouldn't want to point a public address at this.  In the correct setup you could also have the proxy (`nginx`) serve static files (javascript/css) itself as it is good at this, thus lightening the load on the application server (`uwsgi`).  This is well documented.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using node red and access your sensor data on the node red dashboard via any device connected to the same network.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking to access the Pi outside the network